# How to update wifi RSSI values without a click button

Tags: wifi, rssi

Basically, I can list the values of RSSI in a ListView through a SimpleAdapter.

```
public class ActivityListarRedes extends MainActivity {


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listar_redes);


    List<Map<String, String>> l = listaRedes();


    String[] from = { "ExampleId", "ExampleName" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter ad = new SimpleAdapter(this, l, simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);




}

public List<Map<String, String>> listaRedes() {

        networks = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
        wifi.startScan();
        networks = wifi.getScanResults();

        List<Map<String, String>> l = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        for (ScanResult net : networks) {
            Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("ExampleId", "Rede: " + net.SSID);
            m.put("ExampleName", "RSSI: " + net.level + "dBm");
            l.add(m);
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Now, I would like to know if it's possible to update the values of RSSI given by method "listaRedes" which is a List. Maybe I could call the method "listaRedes" during some time until I pause it or click in some button to pause.

Will be that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: You can take a look at my demo for RF measurements using Android device, here:

https://github.com/panosvas/Measurements

where you can find an implementation of WiFi measurements one after another. I have also created a Server for storing these measurements as well as a remote trigger app using UDP packets where you can find here:

https://github.com/panosvas/IndoorPositioningServer

It is possible to update your list. You can take a look in my answer here:

[Wifi Scanner which scans 20 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059997/wifi-scanner-which-scans-20-times/27169311#27169311)

In order to adapt it to your needs you don't want the counter and instead of it, in the onRecieve each time you will trigger again the task that calls the startScan() method.

Don't forget to unregister the listener on the onDestroy.

Hope this helps.